# How to handle the token validation in backend

Tags: python-3.x, security, flask, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I am new to implementing security authentication on rest api. I am trying to implement oauth2 authorization from aws cognito user pool.

```
from flask import  Flask,jsonify,render_template,request

import requests

import socket

app = Flask(__name__)

name='Umesh'
App_client_id = 'cleintId'
App_client_secret = 'clientSecret'
url = 'https://myurl.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com'
targetApi = 'https://myTargetApi/v1/product'



class setTokenCache():
    cache=''



obj= setTokenCache()
#print("Acces token is ", obj.cache)

@app.route('/login')
def index():

    try:
        grant_type = 'client_credentials'
        response = requests.post(url + '/oauth2/token',
                                 auth=(App_client_id, App_client_secret),
                                 data={'grant_type': grant_type, 'client_id': App_client_id,
                                       'client_secret': App_client_secret})

        print("Staus code", response)
        if response.status_code!=200:
            return "You are not authenticated"
        else:
            result = response.json()
            obj.cache = result['access_token']
            print("Access token is",obj.cache)
            return "You are Logined"
    except socket.gaierror as e:
        print("Unable to get the r")
```

### API 1 Login

Here is the api returns #'You are Logined', if its authenticated with the access token just generated.Just consider its a login part.

### API 2 Accessing the productDetails

Now i have this API, where i want to get the valid response using the above generated access token.

```
@app.route('/getProductDetails', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def productDetails():

    print("Access token is",obj.cache)
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken, 'Accept': 'application/json'}
    try:
        response = requests.get(targetApi, headers=headers)
        return response.json()
    except socket.gaierror as e:
        print("Unable to get the r")
```

Here i need to pass the #accessToken in order to get the valid response or otherewise it will return, #unauthrized

## Expected:

Now i would like to know how should i implement this security over this api in such way that

1. It should consume the above created accessToken till it expired in order to get the valid response from the api

```
 http://127.0.0.1:5000/getProductDetails
```

OR
 2. How to ensure that how browser/client would consume the same token while navigating from API 1 to API  till it expired

Appreciate if anybody can help on this?

Comment: `response = requests.get(targetApi, headers=headers)`

What is happening now if you pass an expire token at headers. I mean `targetApi` reponse 401 or something else. 
I am observing  `/getProductDetails` is acting as a extra layer which just forward request only adding token. Why don't we call `targetApi` from browser?

Comment: Hi @Saiful Azad, you mean to first call the api1- http://127.0.0.1:5000/login, so that the client will be authenticated and access token will be cached in the browser. Now if i call the 'target api' on another tab in the same browser, will browser authenticate to get the response from 'target api' ? Now when i called  the 'target api', i am getting 'Unauthorized"' message. i tested the same on post man manually, which is perfectly working fine by passing the token on target api's header's.  Please let me know if i wrong in this case and help me with the approcah?

Comment: If token is stored in localStorage in browser you can call target API from any tab on same browser. From browser you must call target API with Authorization Header. Again plz explain why need the `/getProductDetails` at flask?

Comment: Hi @SaifulAzad initially i thought of binding/associating 'target api' in '/getProductDetails' at flask, but later as you suggested,  i called 'target api' directly after i called the '/login', but it was throwing 'Unauthorized' message . It looks like token not being stored in the local storage in browser, please correct me if i am wrong here. so how to call target API with Authorization Header in browser?

Comment: Please watch your browser request header. Make sure there is the token. I think u r stuck in passing token from browser. Search in stackoverflow how to pass token from browser. You may use `fetch` from browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of Cognito token validation there is some sample NodeJS code below and you should find a library for your programming language. Also the below online tool can be useful for understanding the validation process:

- [Cognito token validation in NodeJS](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.serverless/blob/master/src/plumbing-oauth/src/oauth/oauthAuthenticator.ts)
- [In memory token validation write up](https://authguidance.com/2017/12/06/azure-ad-api-token-validation/)